# Can't write image data to path. Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, image, file, filesystems

Okay I can't find help with this anywhere.

ALL of my paths are set to 755 (which should be sufficient access) but I still get the error.

My storage and public folders are linked.

Here's my code:

```
if (Input::hasFile('file')) {
  $image = Image::make($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);
  $image->fit(200);
  $image->save('public/avatars/user77.jpg');
}
```

Comment: check root path of SAVE method. May cause bad path like ... F:\web\public/avatars/user77.jpg

Comment: @Topher Can you please include the error that you are getting.

Comment: Can't write image data to path (public/avatars/user77.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Are you using [Intervention](http://image.intervention.io/api/stream) for `Image`?  I ran into a similar issue a few months ago.  I ended up getting the image data from `Image` using `stream()` and then using Laravel's `Storage` facade to save it like this.

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;

if (Input::hasFile('file')) {
  $image = Image::make($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'])->fit(200)->stream('jpg');
  Storage::put('public/avatars/user77.jpg', $image);
}
```

See [this article](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/filesystem) for more about Laravel's filesystem if needed.

Answer (score 0):

check for directory existence , if there is no such directory you will create it :

```
 if (!file_exists($save_path)) {
            mkdir($save_path, 666, true);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to come up with a solution without the need for [Intervention](http://image.intervention.io/), which my project does not allow:

```
if ($request->hasFile('file')) {
  $image = file_get_contents($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);
  Storage::disk('images')->put('user77.jpg', $image);
}
```

`file_get_contents` from my understanding is usually for external urls and what have you, but this solution worked for my images. This was especially handy because I'm using the [Froala](https://www.froala.com/wysiwyg-editor/docs/concepts/image/manager) editor, so I am limited in how I send the request.